# Select between range of values in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
-- Purchases --
Id | IdProvider | Date | Observations
```

and

```
-- PurchasesDetails --
Id | IdProduct | Quantity | Price
```

where Purchases.Id = PurchasesDetails.Id

I want to make a SQL query where it returns all the purchases between a range of price (The price info is on PurchasesDetails table -> Quantity*Price)

For example: Get all the purchases that costed more than 0$ but less than 500$

I've tried this:

> SELECT * FROM Purchases INNER JOIN PurchasesDetails ON Purchases.Id = PurchasesDetails.Id WHERE Purchases .Id  sum(PurchasesDetails.Price*PurchasesDetails.Quantity) BETWEEN 0 AND 500

But it doesn't work. Seems like I'm missing a condition to link up all the PurchasesDetails with the same Id

I think it's a really easy task but I'm stuck there for few hours so all the help are welcome!!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT p.*,
       SUM(pd.Price * pd.Quantity) as purchase_total
FROM Purchases p INNER JOIN
     PurchasesDetails pd
     ON p.Id = pd.Id 
GROUP BY p.Id 
HAVING purchase_total BETWEEN 0 AND 500;
```

Note that `SELECT p.*` is fine with `GROUP BY p.id`, assuming that `id` is unique in `Purchases`.

Comment: Yes sir! that's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!